# Is there a way of uniting Units in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, pascal

I have a bunch of records defined into a few files.

I'd like to "unite" those definitions into a single unit, and use that unit everywhere in my program, to avoid having to reference all these units one by one in the rest of the program.
Is there a way to do so in Delphi (without actually putting everything in one file)?

Something that would allow me to tell the compiler "if a file uses Unit1, it can use Unit2 too without directly referencing it".

Comment: No, that is not possible.

Comment: You could `{$I file.inc}` parts of code in one unit, but the inclusions can't be units themselves, only direct code.

Comment: Using include files here is a big step back. You would need separate include files for interface and implementation parts of the units to include. That alone would make working in these include files a PITA. I would definitely advise against doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is just to make maintaining unit lists easier you can use type aliases, like in unit2's interface do

```
Uses Unit1 
Type
   TMyBaseType = Unit1.TMyBaseType;
```

Now if you import unit2, the relevant type of unit1 is also visible.

Comment: Hey, not what I was hoping for but it works, and is especially useful when refactoring. Thanks !